# Chaining two VPNs using a VPS

Tags: vpn, routing, vps

I want to create a VPN chain with two different VPN providers and a Virtual Private Server with a static IP between, so, the configuration would look like that:

```
User ----> Commercial VPN ----> VPS ----> Another commercial VPN ----> Internet
```

Using VPS here is due to the fact that it has yet another IP address. VPS has only one physical interface. Basically, it should work like a Tripple VPN chain.

My question is if it's possible and, if yes, how can I configure a VPS to accept packets from one VPN and redirect them through another?

Comment: Why not? The VPS would just run two VPN clients and connect to each VPN, then route traffic between them. But it seems rather pointless.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for the reply. In fact, I want a second VPN to see a VPS IP, and VPS not to see a user's IP address. It's only about anonymity. And couldn't you explain how I can set up this configuration? As far as I understand, the first VPN client should run on a user's machine to connect to the VPN?

Comment: If all you want is anonymity, don't do any of this. Just use Tor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick & easy anonimity solutions:**

- Use VPN provider you trust
- Use Commercial VPN over commercial VPN
- Use TOR

**Tailored Solution:**

It is possible to chain vpn like this but it's a bit tricky: `client => vpn => vps => vpn => internet`

1- Setup a VPN server in VPS & test:`client => vps(vpn) => internet`

2- Add a static route to VPS for your client's public IP:

`Linux: ip route add <client pub ip> via <vps gateway>`

`Windows: route add -p <client pub ip> mask 255.255.255.255 <vps gateway>`

> This will keep your client remote session connected to vps when you
>   connect VPS to VPN service in next step.

3- Connect VPS to VPN provider & check connectivity to internet: `vps => vpn => Internet`

4- Test connectivity from: 'client => vps(vpn) => vpn => internet'

5- Connect client to vpn and then dial your vps(vpn) which is already connected to another vpn to internet: `client => vpn => vps(vpn) => vpn => internet`

> After connecting your client to vpn you can only dial vps(vpn) if its listening to its connected vpn's pub IP.

OR

> Just add your first VPN's pub ip as static route to VPS following step-2.

Answer (score 0):

Working configuration of vps chaining. [VPS Chaining-Tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdIHk.png)

client 1================== vps1 ==================== vps2

1.1.1.1 ================== 2.2.2.2================== 3.3.3.3

10.9.0.2   ==========>>>10.9.0.1

====================== 10.8.0.2 ============>10.8.0.1

**Change iptables/route/rule in vps1**

```
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 ! -d 10.9.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 2.2.2.2

iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -i tun1 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT 

iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.9.0.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.9.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.8.0.2

ip route add default via 10.8.0.2 table 120 

ip rule add from 10.9.0.0/24 table 120
```

**Edit Openvpn server.conf file on vps1**

```
nano /etc/openvpn/server/server.conf
```

```
push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"

route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```